# Как добавить значение по ключу в Map java

Tags: java, map

Надо, чтобы при добавлении ключа и значения добавлялось значение

```
Алексей 3000
Дмитрий 9000
Антон 3000
Алексей 7000
Антон 8000
```

Пример вывода:

```
{Алексей=[10000], Дмитрий=[9000], Антон=[11000]}
```

Comment: и в чём вопрос? что не получилось?

Comment: ну у меня добавить значение не получается, а получается только перезаписать значение

Comment: покажите код, в вопрос его добавьте

Answer (score 1):

При использовании метода put, Map перезаписывает значение по ключу, если оно есть, а если его нет, то просто вставляет.

Вам нужно

- Проверить есть ли значение для ключа

  - Если есть, то получить их
  - Прибавить к ним нужное число
- Положить пару ключ-значение в Map`у

Примерно так:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        updateValue(map, "Алексей", 3000);
        updateValue(map, "Дмитрий", 9000);
        updateValue(map, "Антон", 3000);
        updateValue(map, "Алексей", 7000);
        updateValue(map, "Антон", 8000);

        System.out.println(map.toString());
    }


    public static void updateValue(Map<String, Integer> map, String key, Integer value) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, map.get(key) + value);
        } else {
            map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @никита-снигиревиch не забудьте пометить ответ, как решение, чтобы ваш вопрос не был в списках неотвеченных. Спасибо.